# Como fazer uma Consulta para selecionar as linhas cuja soma dos valores seja igual a 100 (ex)?

Tags: mysql, sql, query

Como faço para realizar uma consulta para selecionar as linhas cuja soma dos valores seja igual a 100?

Tenho uma tabela de extrato bancário de um cliente, segue tabela:

| id_cliente | Descrição | Valor |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 51420 | linha 1 | 8,89 |
| 51420 | linha 2 | 24,56 |
| 51420 | linha 3 | 15,67 |
| 51420 | linha 4 | 53,63 |
| 51420 | linha 5 | 6,14 |
| 51420 | linha 6 | 14,15 |

Usando como exemplo a tabela acima, a consulta realizada deve retornar o resultado abaixo:

| id_cliente | Descrição | Valor |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 51420 | linha 2 | 24,56 |
| 51420 | linha 3 | 15,67 |
| 51420 | linha 4 | 53,63 |
| 51420 | linha 5 | 6,14 |

```
(24,56 + 15,67 + 53,63 + 6,14 = 100)
```

Comment: Não duplique perguntas, siga as orientações fornecidas na [pergunta original](/questions/591203/desafio-consulta-para-selecionar-as-linhas-cuja-soma-dos-valores-seja-igual-a-1#comment1028194_591203) e melhore-a, clicando em `Editar` (restaurando-a se necessário). Os comentários, aqui, foram desabilitados para que continue na pergunta original.